# How to program loop with two different variables

Tags: php

Imagine you want to add the sum of 2 dice so the output looks like this in 6 lines:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 5 6 ... 7 8... 8 9...
```

By only programming a single loop ?

I tried to do it with nested loops but could figure out the logic for it.

Comment: 1) sum of 2 dice - this to mean, two dice rolls added together or the sum of all dice rolls over a period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with one while loop and two variables for two dices.

```
<?php
$x = 1;
$y = 1;

while ( $x <= 6 ) {
    echo $x + $y;

    $y++;

    if ( $y > 6 ) {
        $y = 1;
        $x++;
    }
}
```

It's essentially a mechanical counter. When the first wheel completes a rotation, it resets, and advances the second wheel. Except in this case they are dice. When $y is greater than six, it resets and advances $x.

You would use similar code when dealing with dates, advancing months when the days tick over etc.

The code would be simpler using two loops.

```
for ( $x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++ ) {    
    for ( $y = 1; $y <= 6; $y++ ) { 
        echo $x + $y;   
    }   
}
```

As this was not allowed, the while loop is the 'first wheel' and the if statement determines when to reset and advance the second.

https://www.hackerrank.com/ is good if you want to practice solving coding problems